# clicking on the div element is not working

Tags: jquery

i'm going to change content color and font-size inside the  div element.
for some reasons it is not working.
here is my code 
html

```
<div class='small'>hello there</div>
```

css

```
.small {
    font-size:14px;
    color:red;
}
.large {
    font-size:26px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    color:#444;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('small').on('click', function () {
    $('large').html($(this).clone().removeClass('small')).fadeIn("medium");
});
```

Comment: `'small'` vs `'.small'` and `'large'` vs `'.large'`; you want to match classes, not tag names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/TX7Eg/)**</kbd>

`small` is a class so `.small` and same for `large`

```
$('small').on('click', function () {
    $('large').html($(this).clone().removeClass('small')).fadeIn("medium");
});
```

change it to

```
$('.small').on('click', function () {
    $('.large').html($(this).clone().removeClass('small')).fadeIn("medium");
});
```

Comment: here is my code at jsfiddle but not working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yhrn/)

Comment: what you wanna achieve?

Comment: sorry i found my mistake thanx

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
$('.small').on('click', function () {
  $(this).hide().toggleClass("large").fadeIn("medium");
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rS8s6/1)